# Excel Workbook Opens in an Old Version

Tags: excel, excel-2010

We have a shared Excel workbook on a network drive, which keeps opening in an old layout version. Previously the first two rows were frozen panes, now three rows are frozen, but the second row is hidden.

However users opening the new version, will only see the first and second row (which shall be hidden) frozen with the third row unfrozen. Once a user adapts the frozen panes manually and saves the workbook, he/she will always see the new version from then again. But the changes do not affect the other users, so every user has to change the view manually.

I suppose there is a temporary file saved on every computer, which causes troubles with the new version. I already unshared/reshared the workbook, replaced the file, unfroze/froze the rows, deleted temp files in AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel: No success, yet.

So in short:

- Excel-file stored on network drive
- Old version: 2 rows frozen
- New version: 3 rows frozen, 1 row hidden
- Every user still sees the old version of the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find solution of the root problem, but created a workaround. Supposedly Excel is storing some temp files in different locations, but clearing the files on every computer manually is not feasible.

The workaround consists of six lines of code inside the Workbook_Open() subroutine. Essentially the rows are rearranged by the macro:

```
'Unhide Rows 1 to 3
Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Hidden = False

'Hide Row 2
Rows("2").EntireRow.Hidden = True

'Unfreeze first three rows
Rows("4").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

'Freeze first three rows
Rows("4").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```